# ant design Layout issue with position fixed Sider

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

My layout is header - Content - Footer

And within said Content, I have a Layout of Sider + (inner) Content

Everything behaves as expected, if the Sider is not `position: "fixed"`. However, if I'd wish for the Sider to have `position: "fixed"`, then the inner Content would decide to expand to the entire width of the outer Content, pouring out over the Sider.

Here's the sider:

```
< Sider
    width="25%"
    style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: '100vh',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
    }}
>
```

If I comment out `position: 'fixed'`, things are fine. But I'd like to have a fixed positioned Sider, so that scrolling down on the page, I'd always see the Sider.

and here's the inner Content:

```
<Content
    width="75%"
    style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        // maxWidth: "75%",
        // right: 0,
       // float: "right",
    }}
>
```

I tried various combinations and nothing seems to work with the `position: 'fixed'` Sider. Any suggestions?

Comment: paste whole code!

Comment: Whole code is across multiple files and will run a few pages. Not sure that would help. It would be more helpful to me to hear which parts of the code might be relevant, so that I can post them here

Comment: without UI we cannot do anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `marginLeft` to content:

```
<Content
    width="75%"
    style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        marginLeft: '25%'
    }}
>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Not sure why I didn't think of it before

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is a container that is position fixed, 100 vh & vw, then your inner sections can be scaled ... note that I'm using `display: inline-block` so that the divs can sit beside each other.

[Example 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ljktg?file=src%2Fstyle.css)

This is actually a job for flex layout, but depending on why you're choosing to use a fixed layout, it might not be ideal

[Example 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3av5ph?file=src%2Fstyle.css)

Alternatively (overkill) you can use grids, which I like just due to the range of control you have

[Example 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ucqbjy?file=src%2Fstyle.css)

Comment: Thank you! Please keep this answer here as it addresses the more general problem which may be useful to me down the road and to many others